# Working with large catalog on Magento 1.8 platform. Indexing and Exporting time out

Tags: magento, memory, oscommerce, catalog

I have a large catalog I've imported from oscommerce, 127,428 products to be exact. They've come through to magento as simple products with one image. I have been unsuccessful at getting the indexing to work even at the command line with ssh. It times out or just never finishes.

The second problem I am having is exporting (even just enabled products) it is giving me a memory error. There just doesn't seem to be enough memory to get it to write the export file. I need to edit all the products to add additional pictures and change descriptions and such. I plan to use mage to edit and import the products back in.

Is there anything I can possibly do to get this thing to successfully export 127,000 products without errors?

I am using: System->Import/Export->DataFlow-Profiles -> Export all products

Comment: It would help people answer you question if you outline what you're doing to export the products.  There's multiple ways of doing this in Magneto.

Comment: I've edited my question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with exporting to Google Shopping. It always timed out (probably due to having too many products in my feed).

According to [this exporting from Magento to Google Shopping guide](http://www.internetmarketing.net/2014/blog/how-to-export-magento-product-feed-for-google-shopping.html):
You should change your php.ini settings to these values:

```
ini_set(’max_execution_time’,’1800’);
ini_set(’memory_limit’,’1024M’);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Magmi - http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

It's self explanatory to use. There is a giant wiki with full instructions of how to install and operate it.